# How do I convert an object to an ajax body in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an `express` server that is expecting a user object.  I am submitting the `ajax` request to the server via an `jQuery ajax` call.  Here is my client side code:

```
var user = {
    "first_name": "Jimi",
    "last_name": "Hendrix",
    "email": "jimi@gmail.com"
};
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:9000/stuff',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {user: user}
});
```

The body never makes it to `express`.  Here is my `express` setup.

```
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.send(200);
  } else {
    next();
  }
}

app.post('/stuff', function(req, res) {
    'use strict';
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send(200);
});
```

My `console.log(req.body)` always returns the same thing, 
`body: {}`

What do I need to do for my body to make it across to my server?  Do I need to serialize the data?  I thought I could just attach the object.

Comment: Could you change from `data: {user: user}` to `data: user`?

Comment: In what way do you see that `body` is empty?

Comment: Passing the user object directly should work. Check the browser's developer console for what is being sent. If you see your data, then it's your server that's the problem. By the way, your data type should be 'application/json'.

Comment: @phong vo why would this make a difference? Both methods are supported.

Comment: I changed the `dataType` to `application/json`.  I then attached the object with `data: user`.  When I get in my `express` server and `consolelog(req.body)`, it still returns `{}`.

Comment: When I looked at the docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), the `dataType` should be `json`, not `application/json`.

Comment: I dare say the problem lies with express. I sent your ajax code to my local server (rails) and the Chrome Network console clearly shows that the jquery side worked. (haha, ninja'd by your answer)

Answer (score 0):

In `jQuery`, the `ajax` default `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  With an `express` server, if you want to parse out that type of content, then you have to add the `bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})`.  Now when I `console.log` out my body, then I get exactly what I expect.